# python:compare if string in list

Tags: python, django

I have a problem.
I have an `product.address` like this  'UK some city some road'

And I want to compare this address,if it is start with UK or US or AS or GE
I will save `product.dstore_id = 2`,otherwise, save `product.dstore_id = 1`

My code is like this:

```
area = [UK,US,AS,GE]
for i in area:
    if i in product.address:
        product.dstore_id = 2
    else:
        product.dstore_id = 1
```

But I found this has a big problem,it will compare all the `i`   and save the wrong number
So how can I do to reach it .  Please guide me a bit  Thank you

Answer (score 4):

You could use `any`. This will return `True` if any of the items in your `area` list are present in the `product.address`. You then no longer need the `for` loop.

```
if any(address.startswith(i) for i in area):
    product.dstore_id = 2
else:
    product.dstore_id = 1
```

For example

```
area = ['UK','US','AS','GE']
address =  'UK some city some road'
>>> any(addres.startswith(i) for i in area)
True
```

Comment: `startswith` is safer & more efficient, eg `product.dstore_id = 2 if any(address.startswith(i) for i in area) else 1`